# CSS geometric image not working properly

Tags: html, css

Im having some issue to make this image on my page:

```css
.l-bs {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.l-tr {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 25px solid black;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="l-bs">
  <div class="l-tr">
  </div>
</div>
```

Im using exactly the same code but instead of a trapezium, it's showing a triangle in my page

To make the same image I have to double the **.l-tr** width.

Does anyone knows whats happening?

Print: https://i.gyazo.com/1da9b63fdeea30604036bbff3707f3b3.png

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Show us the code you are using, the above code generates a trapezium, but from your question I think your problem is slightly different

Comment: @LemuelBotha Thats the Problem. I've tested. There's literally nothing between the <body> tag and the <div class="l-bs">. The result is the same. I can't find a reason for this behavior.

Comment: can you also show what css currently have for l-bs